# Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rxjs

I'm getting the following warning:
"**Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
in AddComment (at CommentCard.js:50)
in div (created by Comment**" (line 50 from CommentCard is the line where the AddComment component is)

I have the **CommentCard** component which displays a comment with the help of the **Comment** component from ant design. I use the children property of the Comment component in order to display the **AddComment** component for a specific comment.

The **AddComment** component adds a reply to a comment.
To display the **AddComment** component for the corresponding comment I'm using an array of states and I display the component only for the comments that have the state equal with 1.

After I add a reply I want the **AddComment** component to be removed. To do this I change the state of the comment after the reply was added successfully. I'm getting the warning right after I post a reply.

Here's my CommentCard component

```
function CommentCard(props) {
  const [hasReplyCommentBox, setHasReplyCommentBox] = useState([]);
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const commentStyle = {
    padding: '10px',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    'whiteSpace': 'pre',
    width: '100%'
  };

  function toggleReplyBoxVisibility(commentIndex) {
    var auxState = { ...hasReplyCommentBox };
    auxState[commentIndex] = auxState[commentIndex] ? 0 : 1;
    setHasReplyCommentBox(auxState);
  }

  const actions = [
    <span
      id={"reply-button-" + props.commentIndex}
      onClick={() => toggleReplyBoxVisibility(props.commentIndex)}>
      {t('Reply to')}
    </span>
  ];

  const commentReplyBox = (
    hasReplyCommentBox[props.commentIndex]
      ? <AddComment
          id={props.codeId}
          parentCommentId={props.parentCommentId}
          commentIndex={props.commentIndex}
          toggleReplyBoxVisibility={toggleReplyBoxVisibility}
          updateComments={props.updateComments}
        />
      : null
  );

  return (
    <Comment
      author={props.userId}
      datetime={props.datePosted}
      content={props.body}
      actions={actions}
      children={commentReplyBox}
      style={commentStyle}
    />
  );
}
```

Here's my AddComment component:

```
function AddComment(props) {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const { TextArea } = Input;
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [comment, setComment] = useState();

  const buttonStyle = { float: 'right' };

  function onCommentChange(newComment) {
    setComment(newComment.target.value);
  }

  function resetCommentInput() {
    setComment('');
  }

  function onFormReset() {
    form.resetFields();
  }

  function submitComment() {
    let request = {
      body: comment,
      code_id: props.id,
      line_number: props.lineNumber,
      parent_comment_id: props.parentCommentId
    };
    fetch('/api/comment/add',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(request)
      }
    ).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.success === 1) {
        if (props.parentCommentId) {
          props.toggleReplyBoxVisibility(props.commentIndex);
        }
        props.updateComments();
        resetCommentInput();
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Form form={form} name="comment" className="comment-form"
        onFinish={submitComment}
        id={"add-comment-form" + props.parentCommentId}>
        <Form.Item name="body" label={t('Comment')}>
          <TextArea placeholder={t('Leave a comment')}
            onChange={onCommentChange}
            id={getCommentTextAreaId(props.lineNumber, props.parentCommentId)}
          />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item style={buttonStyle}>
          <Space>
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit"
              id={
                getPostCommentButtonId(props.lineNumber, props.parentCommentId)
              }
              className = "comment-form-button" onClick={onFormReset}>
              {t('Post')}
            </Button>
            {props.parentCommentId
              ? <Button id={"cancel-add-reply-comment-" + props.parentCommentId}
                  type="secondary" className="comment-form-button"
                  onClick={
                    () => props.toggleReplyBoxVisibility(props.commentIndex)
                  }>
                  {t('Cancel')}
                </Button>
              : null
            }
          </Space>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function submitComment() {
    let request = {
      body: comment,
      code_id: props.id,
      line_number: props.lineNumber,
      parent_comment_id: props.parentCommentId
    };
    fetch('/api/comment/add',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(request)
      }
    ).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.success === 1) {
        props.updateComments();
        resetCommentInput();
        // Run resetCommentInput before props.toggleReplyBoxVisibility
        if (props.parentCommentId) {
          props.toggleReplyBoxVisibility(props.commentIndex);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

you should update the component state before unmounting it

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It helped me